# Rewrite in Mediawiki, remove index.php, .htaccess

Tags: apache, htaccess, redirects, 301-redirect, mediawiki

I've just installed Mediawiki on Apache and I want the URL should be:

```
localhost/Main_Page/
localhost/Special:Recent_Changes
...
```

instead of:

```
localhost/index.php/Main_Page/
localhost/index.php/Special:Recent_Changes
```

I've tried many times and in many ways but it still doesn't work. Any suggest for a "exactly" what to do, step by step. Mediawiki docs didn't talk about *.htaccess*. It had only Nginx and lighttpd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This MediaWiki documentation](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aShort_URL/Apache) *does* talk about *.htaccess*.

Answer (score 3):

You can have clean URLs with the following step.

Install the wiki into `http://localhost/w` and **NOT** into `http://localhost/wiki` then Modify the following in **LocalSettings.php** after you have set it up:

```
$wgArticlePath = "/wiki/$1";
```

In the ROOT directory place the following .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

## uncomment this rule if you want to redirect to http://localhost/wiki/Main_Page
# RewriteRule ^/$ /wiki/Main_Page [R]

## do the rewrite
RewriteRule ^wiki/?(.*)$ /w/index.php?title=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Although, the [MediaWiki docs](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aShort_URL/Apache) appear to warn against setting a `title` URL parameter in the rewritten URL: "be sure to never include `?title=$1` or something like it in the rewrite. Including a query will cause MediaWiki's built in handling to be overridden..."

Answer (score 2):

*Try the following code:*

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /mediawiki/index.php?title=$1&actions=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Although, the [MediaWiki docs](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aShort_URL/Apache) appear to warn against setting a `title` URL parameter in the rewritten URL: "be sure to never include `?title=$1` or something like it in the rewrite. Including a query will cause MediaWiki's built in handling to be overridden..."